# using System.Data.SqlClient namespace does not exist?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

Ok Seriously confused here.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 in a Windows Phone 8 project, I have SQLite installed from NuGet into my Visual Studio, as well .NET framework. I type in "using System.Data.SqlClient; and it says the assembly reference is missing? I know this isn't a .DLL as SqlClient is part of the System.Data assembly, however it only provides me with the options of System.Data.Common and System.Data.Linq when using this, not SqlClient, can anyone explain why? Been banging my head over this and googling like mad for hours!

Comment: Which NuGet package did you use? It is likely you need something like `System.Data.SQLite` not `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Cheers lad I think that was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Data.SqlClient` is used for SQL Server, which you probably don't need on WP8. You are looking for [`System.Data.SQLite`](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

so use:

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

Comment: mate you're a legend thank you! I think that was it, bloody hell!